# How to use array in Directory.GetFiles ('path')

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I want to use array in Directory.GetFiles('use array')

I can't use dirs in path of the Directory.GetFiles

```
string path = @"D:\";
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Where(d => !isExcluded(_excludedDirectories, d));
var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirs).Where(d => !isExcluded(_excludedDirectories, d));
```

How I can use it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'use array'? Do you have more than one directory?

Comment: What is the reason for the second WHERE? You have already excluded the unwanted directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because returns an array of DirectoryInfo[] and not a single string so perhaps if you change your code like below it works

```
var files = new List<String>();
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Where(d => !isExcluded(_excludedDirectories, d));
foreach(var item in dirs)
{
foreach(var item1 in Directory.GetFiles(item).Where(d => !isExcluded(_excludedDirectories, d)))
files.Add(item1);
}
```

Comment: foreach (string x in ?)
                {                
                I want to delete the files here
                } <br> what  I have to write in ?

Comment: @KnightM for delete you can use foreach (string x in ?) {File.Delete(x);}

Comment: string x in what?  this is my question

Comment: oh sorry, foreach (string x in files)

Comment: How I can delete all files exclude a particular extension like *.pdf

Comment: @KnightM, ...GetFiles(item).Where(d =>d.extension==".pdf")

Comment: not work for me extension is not valid any other ways like if else

Comment: I think you better upload the code for delete and the error in the new question, so we can help you better

Comment: Telegram or Whtasap  ID?

Comment: @KnightM, no I mean right here in stckoverflow as a new question

Answer (score 1):

This returns a `List` of all files:

```
var List<string> files = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
        .Where(directory => !isExcluded(_excludedDirectories, directory))
        .SelectMany(Directory.GetFiles)
        .Where(file => !isExcluded(_excludedFiles, file))
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can continue linq method-chain like this:

```
string path = @"D:\";
var files = Directory
    .GetDirectories(path)
    .Where(d => !isExcluded(_excludedDirectories, d))
    .Select(Directory.GetFiles)
    .Where(f => !isExcluded(_excludedDirectories, f));
```

If you then want to delete the files, do so:

```
string path = @"D:\";
Directory
    .GetDirectories(path)
    .Where(d => !isExcluded(_excludedDirectories, d))
    .Select(Directory.GetFiles)
    .Where(f => !isExcluded(_excludedDirectories, f))
    .SelectMany(f => f)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(File.Delete);
```